# Compromise between functional programming and imperative programming

Tags: functional-programming, immutability

I've been using a functional programming (FP) style for over a year now, and I can see its advantages.  However, there are circumstances where an imperative style (mutable state, order-dependent statements) is a better fit to the problem and doesn't interfere with the advantages of FP.  I'd like to know if the compromise that I'll describe below is widely used, if it has a name, and if there are any languages or libraries that help to enforce it (similar to the way that Haskell enforces pure FP).

I think that is question is a better fit for StackOverflow, but if the community thinks it should be moved to programmers.stackexchange, I'll move it there.

Two aspects of a program can be immutable: the symbol bindings and the data structures.  Symbol bindings are immutable if declared as "final" in Java or "val" in Scala, data structures are immutable if there are no public methods or functions that can change them in-place.  This makes four cases:

1. immutable symbol bindings, immutable data structures (full FP)
2. immutable symbol bindings, mutable data structures (like "final HashMap x" in Java)
3. mutable symbol bindings, immutable data structures (like "var x: immutable.Map in Scala)
4. mutable symbol bindings, mutable data structures (full imperative)

Immutable data structures are valuable because they don't have to be defensively copied and can take advantage of structural sharing, so I'm only considering #1 and #3.  Mutable symbol bindings can be the source of confusing dependencies, but only if they are shared across a large part of the codebase.  If they are only available within a function as local variables (and therefore also thread-local), they're harmless.

Moreover, it can be very useful to work with mutable symbol bindings on a small scale--- iterative mathematical algorithms are a common use-case for me.  All of my local state-changing for loops could be reworked into recursion, but it's hard to see the benefit.  When I write the algorithm, either my pseudocode is local state-changing or the Fortran example that I'm porting is local state-changing, and converting it into recursive functions obfusgates its meaning, rather than enlghtening it.  Afterward, the compiler has to reverse the process, turning it into machine code that looks a lot like the "intuitive" original, possibly at a loss of efficiency if that conversion isn't perfect.

But on the other hand, the large scale structure of the program (everything that doesn't fit onto a single screen) is greatly improved by immutable data structures and functions without side-effects.  In case #3, we still get referential transparency (of functions), Haskell-like lazy evaluation would be possible, we get all the advantages of immutable data (all values are immutable, though local symbols are not), and we also get the smooth transition to parallelization, though the scale of granularity is a function.

Of course, I can do whatever I want in my own programs; I'm asking if this is a common style, if it has a name, and if there are any languages or libraries that support/enforce it.  (Clojure transients are an example of case #2, data structures that are temporarily mutable.  Clojure's with-local-vars emulates #3, but with a lot of overhead--- it was significantly slower than local "var" in Scala, so it's not being translated to machine code in a straightforward way, which I guess is implicit in what I'm asking.  Other than that, I haven't found any examples.)